# Different methods for finding the minimum of $|x-2y|$ when $x^2+1=2y^2$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, analytic-geometry

For $x, y \in \Bbb R$, $x^2 + 1 = 2y^2$, find the minimum of $|x - 2y|$.

At a glance I found that the point $(x, y)$ lies on a hyperbola and $|x - 2y|$ is just the distance between the point and the line $x - 2y = 0$ times $\sqrt 5$. Now this problem can be solved by using derivatives.

My question is: are there any other solutions? I want to find some other beautiful solutions to this interesting problem. All methods are accepted as long as they are rigorous.

Comment: Deriving is not needed.

Comment: Note that $|x - 2y|$ is minimized exactly where $(x -2y)^2$ is minimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculations give us
$$(x-2y)^2=2(x-y)^2+1 \ge 1$$

Thus we have $$|x-2y| \ge 1$$ With the equality holding when $x=y=\pm 1$.

Comment: You need to argue that a point on the curve exists with $|x-2y|=1$.  For this note that your (first) inequality is exact if and only if $x=y$, and plugging this into the equation of the curve we get $(x,y)=\pm(1,1)$ are the only such points on the curve, and both of them satisfy $|x-2y|=1$.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy That seems pretty simple to figure out from what I gave, So I left it for the OP to figure out.

Comment: Well, the devil's in the (simple) details.  Simply bounding the modulus below does not prove the minimum that is suggested is actually attained.  It's sort of implicitly there in the use of the equation of the curve to manipulate the equation, I just personally like seeing that made more clear.

Comment: Great, but how did you think of $(x-2y)^2=2(x-y)^2+1\ge1$? Following the same method, I can get many other "minima" that are smaller than $1$ yet cannot be attained. So how did you come up with $1$?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie I didn't come up with $1$. Instead, I let $x^2-4xy+ay^2+(4-a)y^2$ and put $y^2=\frac{x^2+1}{2}$ and tried to make a square.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$2y^2-x^2=1$$

WLOG $\sqrt2y=\sec2t,x=\tan2t$

$$u=x-2y=\dfrac{\sin2t-\sqrt2}{\cos2t}$$

$$\sqrt2=\sin2t-u\cos2t\iff\sqrt{\dfrac2{u^2+1}}=\sin\left(2t-\arccos\dfrac1{1+u^2}\right)\le1$$

$$u^2+1\ge2\iff|u|\ge1$$

Comment: Great! Just one more thing: you should show that $|u|$ can attain the minimum $1$ in your answer.